# posts_per_page using custom value

Tags: wordpress

i have created a custo post type and wp_query the custom postype like this
$number_of_posts = get_option('news_blurb_blurbs_per_page_setting');
            $default_posts = 3;

```
        $args = array(

        'post_type'      => 'all_news_blurbs',
        'orderby'        => 'date',
        'order'          => 'DESC',
        'numberposts'   => 3,
        'posts_per_page' => (isset($number_of_posts) ? $number_of_posts : $default_posts)
```

it works fine when custom values is selected in select tag but when black the default should be 3 is not working

Answer (score 1):

You need to add in condition like below

```
 $number_of_posts = get_option('news_blurb_blurbs_per_page_setting'); 

 if(!empty($number_of_posts) && $number_of_posts!='')
    $number_of_posts = 3;
```

That's it it will work.